# "FF FF" is getting dumped as "FD" on some of the computers with Java Scripting API

Tags: java, javascript, io

I am facing issues with the [Java Scripting API together with JavaScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) on some of the PCs. After analyzing the dumped file, I noticed that "FF FF" is geeting printed as "FD" on some of the PCs. Below is the code snippet:

```
var outputfile = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
var byte_data_array = getMyByteArrayData(somebytearray); 
var data_string = new java.lang.String(byte_data_array);
outputfile.writeBytes(data_string);
```

Comment: I have never seen `RandomAccessFile` or `java.lang.String` in JavaScript. Where does this come from?

Comment: @FelixKling these are coming from Java. (importPackage(java.io);
and importPackage(java.lang);).

Comment: How can you import Java into JavaScript? Those are two different programming languages.

Comment: @FelixKling Please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsimport It gives example about how to import java packages in java script.

Comment: Interesting. That's the information you forgot to mention in your question (apart from missing the `java` tag). Because I believe that 99% of JavaScript code is not written in this context.

Comment: Ok, so you're running JavaScript code within Java's scripting engine - that's a rather exotic case. It's no surprise that it looks to people like you're confusing Java and JavaScript because of the name (a common beginner's mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting the data from bytes to String without specifying an encoding (which uses the local-dependant platform default encoding), then write it to a file using the `writeBytes()` method that is documented in the API doc as discarding the higher-order byte of each character.

What did you expect? I'm actually surprised the result has any resemblance at all to the original data.

What you most likely should do is replace the last two lines with this:

```
outputfile.write(byte_data_array);
```

And always remember: bytes are for data, Strings are for text, and if you convert between them, you always need to pay attention to what encoding is used.